# php multiplication calculator with results

Tags: php, html

I wrote a script years ago for a simple php calculator that did multiplication price per square feet, total square feet and visits per week, and the total would be the sum of the three. I cant get it to multiply properly, i can't even get it to display the price per square feet.

I haven't written any scripts in so long, i cant remember anymore what I am doing, and I couldn't find a solution anywhere to help me figure it out again. Or one I could understand anyway. So if anyone could help me figure this out, i would greatly appreciate it. Maybe js would be better? I don't know it's literally been years since i have done any of this

php code

```
$priceper = 0.11;
$sqfeet = $_POST['sqfeet'];
$perweek = $_POST['perweek'];

// Calculate the total:
$total = $priceper * $sqfeet * $perweek;
```

html

```
<div><p>Fill out this form to calculate the total cost:</p>

<form action="" method="post">

 <p> Price per square foot <? echo $priceper ?></p>

<p>Square Feet: <input type="text" name="sqfeet"></p>

<p>Visits per week: <input type="text" name="perweek" size="5"></p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate!">

</form>
<p>TOTAL: <? echo $total; ?>


</div>
```

I tried redoing the whole thing using JS, here's what I have:

HTML

```
<form>
Price per Sq Foot: <input type="text" id="priceper" value="0.11" disabled placeholder="$0.11"><br>
Sq Feet: <input type="text" id="sqfeet">
Visits: <input type="text" id="perweek">
<input type="button" value="Multiply Total" onclick="multiply()">
<div class="out" id="multiplyresult"></div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var  result=getId('Total'),
     multiplyresult=getId('multiplyresult'),
     n1,n2,n3;

function getValues(){ 
    n1=getId('priceper').value,
    n2=getId('sqfeet').value,
    n3=getId('perweek').value;
}
console.log((n1)*(n2)*(n3));
window.multiply= function(){ getValues(); 
multiplyresult.innerText=(n1)*(n2)*(n3); };
function getId(x){ return document.getElementById(x);}
```

I got thisto work, but I would prefer to have the price per sq foot hard coded, instead of a disabled input, not sure how to do that so it gets the value, and I would like the results to be displayed in normal text, not in a text area box. If i could get some help with those 2 things, id be all set

Comment: After doing some research, I think Ajax would be the best solution, unfortunately , I know absolutely nothing about ajax. But i will try messing around with somethings and ill see what I can come up with

Comment: Is the PHP rendered in the same page as the HTML? It has to be if you have an action of ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same but self contained client side

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cost Calculator</title>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const pricePerSquareFoot = 0.11;
      const sqFeetField = document.getElementById('sqfeet');
      const perWeekField = document.getElementById('perweek');
      const totalCostSpan = document.getElementById('totalCost');
      const form = document.getElementById('costForm');

      document.getElementById('pricePerSquareFoot').textContent = pricePerSquareFoot;
      form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault(); // stop submission
        const sqFeet = +sqFeetField.value;
        const perWeek = +perWeekField.value;
        const total = pricePerSquareFoot * sqFeet * perWeek;
        totalCostSpan.textContent = total.toFixed(2);
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #f4f4f4;
    }
    
    #costForm {
      background: #fff;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    
    #costForm p {
      margin: 10px 0;
    }
    
    input[type="number"] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 8px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /* Added for consistent sizing */
    }
    
    #calculateButton {
      background-color: #007bff;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    #calculateButton:hover {
      background-color: #0056b3;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>Fill out this form to calculate the total cost:</p>
    <form id="costForm">
      <p> Price per square foot: <span id="pricePerSquareFoot"></span></p>
      <p>Square Feet: <input type="number" id="sqfeet"></p>
      <p>Visits per week: <input type="number" id="perweek" size="5"></p>
      <button type="submit" id="calculateButton">Calculate!</button>
    </form>
    <p>TOTAL: <span id="totalCost"></span></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML form has three input fields: `sqfeet`, `perweek`, and a `submit` button. The action attribute of the form is empty, meaning it will submit the form to the same page (index.php or whatever the file name you are using). The method attribute is set to "post" indicating that form data will be sent as POST parameters.

> When a form is submitted with a button (or input type) named "submit", and a POST method the browser sends the form data to the server using the HTTP POST method.

In the PHP code, **$_POST** is an associative array that contains data sent to the server as part of the HTTP POST request. The keys of this array correspond to the "name" attributes of the form elements.

`$sqfeet = $_POST['sqfeet'];` retrieves the value entered in the "sqfeet" field from the POST data and assigns it to the PHP variable `$sqfeet`.

Similarly for the other fields as well. But I think there is been a mistake in the line `$priceper = $_POST['0,10'];` of PHP code attempts to retrieve a value from the $_POST array using '0,10' as the key. The value assigned to `$priceper` would be whatever value is associated with the `'0,10'` key in the POST data. It's uncommon to use a string like '0,10' as a key for form data. Typically, form field names are *alphanumeric strings* without commas. It's more common to use field names like **'priceper'** or any valid string if you are retrieving the data from the posted input field from the Form. And also there is no such input field with "name" attribute `'0,10'` to be found in your HTML code.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there are a couple of issues in your PHP code.

**Issue 1**

First, in the HTML form, the PHP [echo statement](https://www.tutsinsider.com/php/php-echo-statement/) is incorrect. It should be `<?php echo $priceper; ?>` instead of `<? echo ' . $priceper . '; ?>`.

**Issue 2**

Secondly, when retrieving the values from [html form](https://www.tutsinsider.com/html/html-forms/) using `$_POST`, you should use the correct keys. It seems like you're trying to access the price per square foot using `$_POST['0,10']`. Instead, use a more appropriate name for the input, like `priceper`:

```
$priceper = $_POST['priceper'];
$sqfeet = $_POST['sqfeet'];
$perweek = $_POST['perweek'];
```

Make sure to update the corresponding input field in your HTML form:

```
<p> Price per square foot: <input type="text" name="priceper"></p>
```

Once these adjustments are made, it should help resolve the multiplication issue you're facing.

Comment: I have made changes to fix the echo statement, but i am still having issues getting the total to display, for some reason it is blank, I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: csn you please share screenshot

Comment: This is an AI generated answer